# Geometric Relationship between Two Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, transpose

Consider two column vectors such that $a = (1,2,3)^T$ and $b = (-3,3,-1)^T$.

What is the geometric relationship between $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Do you know the dot product?

Comment: How do you define "geometric relationship"? They are orthogonal, if you mean that. What are *your* thoughts?

Comment: You might wish to use $[\;]^T$ instead of $()^T$, since it is common to list both column and row vector components as $(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_i)$, but square brackets $[\;]$ are only used for the matrix notation ($[x_1, x_2, \dots, x_i]$ for row vectors, and $[x_1, x_2, \dots, x_i]^T$ for column vectors).  This is not a hard rule, nor do everyone agree, but ensuring you use notation that is not accidentally misunderstood is useful.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Because the dot product vanishes, the vectors are perpendicular.

Answer (score 0):

The dot product of two vectors is 
$$\left(\begin{matrix}a_1\\a_2\\a_3\end{matrix}\right)\cdot\left(\begin{matrix}b_1\\b_2\\b_3\end{matrix}\right)=a_1b_1+a_2b_2+a_3b_3=|a||b|\cos\theta.$$
Where $|a|$ is the length of the vector $a$. 
Try computing $a_1b_1+a_2b_2+a_3b_3$ and see what your result is.  Using $|a||b|\cos\theta$, can you interpret your result?